# PowerShell find files one by one

Tags: file, powershell, time

I have a script that examines a folder and finds the oldest file (by LastWrittenTime) and writes the found file's LastWriteTime to a log file.

If I run this script again I would like it to find the next oldest file, which has LastWriteTime greater than the one previously written to the log file.

But there is a problem. My scipt can find only the oldest file in the folder each time and ignores the one in the log file.

My script:

```
$programdir = "C:\Data\PowerShell\Learning"
$folder = "C:\Data\PowerShell\Learning\folder" #there is the files
$TimeLog = "$programdir\LastFileDate.log" #this file contains the last found file's LastWriteTime attribute
$LastWriteTime = Get-Content $TimeLog
$File = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Last 1 | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $LastWriteTime}
Clear-Content $TimeLog
$File.LastWriteTime | Set-Content $TimeLog
```

Comment: get all file times and compare them yourself

Answer (score 1):

You immediately cripple your selection set with this line. Specifically *where* you have `Select-Object -Last 1`:

> ```
> $File = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Last 1 | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $LastWriteTime}
> ```

In the second last pipe statement you limit your selection set to 1 file. Then afterwards you apply your date logic. You need to filter on your dates *first* then grab the appropriate entry.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File | 
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $LastWriteTime} | 
    Select-Object -First 1
```

There are other similar approaches that would work as well.

---

Also...

> ```
> Clear-Content $TimeLog
> $File.LastWriteTime | Set-Content $TimeLog
> ```

That is redundant since `Set-Content` will overwrite by default. You can remove the `Clear-Content`.

While this is not an issue in your code be aware that `$LastWriteTime`, as returned by `Get-Content`, is a string and not a `datetime` object. Since it is on the RHS of the statement in your where clause is cast as a `[datetime]` for the purpose of evaluating the clause.

Also be careful that your code could act differently if there is more than one line in your `$timelog`

Comment: Must start with the oldest! So the Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $LastWriteTime} isn't correct for it. Must with -gt $LastWriteTime. And at the end it will part of Do - While loop!

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @NorbertKiss Did you actually try it first? In practice this worked fine. We need to grab all the first before that date first and grab the latest one.